# nginx $document_root with subdirectories insert the subdirectory in its path

Tags: php, nginx, webserver, fpm

I'm working with subdirectories. I want "babylon/webmail" to go to my rainloop webmail client.

```
location ^~ /webmail {
    root /srv/rainloop/public_html;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /webmail/index.php?$query_string;
    access_log /srv/rainloop/logs/access.log;
    error_log /srv/rainloop/logs/error.log;
    index index.php;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/scripts.log scripts;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        #fastcgi_index index.php;
        #fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
        #fastcgi_keep_conn on;
        #include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        #fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        #fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

        #try_files $uri =404;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        #fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /srv/rainloop/public_html/index.php;
        #include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

    location ^~ /webmail/data {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

However this

```
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
```

doesn't work at all. It prints out: /srv/rainloop/public_html/**webmail**/index.php; That file doesn't exist in the directory structure, but: /srv/rainloop/public_html/index.php

```
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /srv/rainloop/public_html/index.php;
```

P.S.: After hardcoding, I don't get any error at all, but the page is blank with some rainloop code source code.

Answer (score 1):

The path to the file is calculated by concatenating the value of `root` to the URI. The URI contains `/webmail/index.php`, otherwise it would not match the `location` block.

You probably mean to use `alias` instead of `root` as that directive removes the value of the prefix `location` when calculating the path to the file. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias) for details.

```
location ^~ /webmail {
    alias /srv/rainloop/public_html;
    if (!-e $request_filename) { rewrite ^ /webmail/index.php last; }

    ...

    location ~ \.php$ {
        if (!-f $request_filename) { return 404; }
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
}
```

Avoid using `try_files` and `alias` in the same block, due to [this long term issue](https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/97), and see [this caution](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) on the use of `if`. Use `$request_filename` for the SCRIPT_FILENAME value.